# text-decoration: none and color not working

Tags: html, css

I am making a hearer using HTML and CSS. I am using `li` tags to create menu and `a` tag inside that. I am trying to apply some CSS properties to `a` tag however it is not working. Please help, below is my code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aesthetic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='header'>
        <div class='name'>Aesthetic</div>
        <div class='menu'>
            <ul>
                <li style="background:#c3c3c3;color:#000000;"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.header{
    background-color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.name{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 10%
}

.menu{
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    right: 10%;
}

.menu ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 60%;
    color: #ffffff;
};

.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Define ‘*not working*’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray semi-colon (`;`)

```
.menu ul li{
    ...
}; /* <-- HERE */
```

Which is causing the following block to be ignored.

Working example:

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.name {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 10%
}
.menu {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  right: 10%;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <div class='name'>Aesthetic</div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <ul>
      <li style="background:#c3c3c3;color:#000000;"><a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @festive, also I am unable to increase the height of li in menu. I want gray hightlighted to be broad around "Home", please suggest. Below is my css for li

.menu ul li{
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 20px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #ffffff;
}